# Scale Cloud Service Instance Count via .NET Azure SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-sdk-.net

I want to scale the instance count of a cloud service worker role up and down programmatically via the .NET Azure SDK. How do I do this? All I have found up to this point is doing this via PowerShell.

Comment: Did you ever find a Good resource for accomplishing this?  We have a similar use case

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: While I'm waiting for a call back check this out https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arunrakwal/2012/05/10/azure-scale-application-increase-or-decrease-the-number-of-role-instance/ and this although I don't see the queue stuff in the auto scale https://github.com/Azure/azure-content-nlnl/blob/master/articles/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-scale.md

Comment: I chatted with MS for a couple hours about this and the possible solutions.  The best approach for this today is to use the Azure Batch Service which allows you to create a pool with 0 nodes in it and you can programatically change the TargetDedicated count to whatever you want.  The only difference is you need to create an app that can run as a task or as a pool app. I created a working prototype, it runs pretty well on Batch.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be a step by step on how to auto-scale azure applications: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-autoscaling-application-block/

Comment: I don't want autoscaling. I was hoping to get an answer to the question. Also, the link is broken.